# MicroCloud Virtual Machine

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am working on taint tracking model on java framework, and I have enhanced existing core java classes such as String, StringBuilder etc. and have build a virtual machine based on these new (self edited) java framework.

Does the CloudFoundry runs on the local virtual machine, or creates its own one?
I am using it with VMware player.

If it creates its own VM, is there any way to get SSH connection and set up new VM (my self edited one)?

This project is purely for academic purposes so Sun's T&C are not braked.

Kind regards,
Assel

Comment: Your own VM, or just your own Java Class Library?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It should be modified VM and Class Library.

Comment: I have changed my default JAVA_HOME to modified version already, and I need to test web applications by deploying them on MicroCloud. These web applications were vulnerable to SQL injections, and now I want to see whether they are actually protected or not. Does MicroCloud rely on my local VM and Class Library?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Micro Cloud Foundry, then everything runs inside the virtual machine, including the Java VM used for executing your code. You use vmc push to deploy your code into the Micro Cloud Foundry instance, and it executes inside there.

Remember that you do not have access to modify the system JVM on the "real" (non-Micro) cloudfoundry.com or other Cloud Foundry instances like AppFog, you use the version that is already deployed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but because it is runs locally on my machine, is there any way to modify JVM? I figured out that we can have ssh connection and even install some applications there, but for some reason it doesn't show JAVA_HOME path, so that I could modify it. 
The project which I am doing is Academic, so it is dynamic taint tracking on Java, without any modification to the source code of application. This is something that Cloud needs.

Comment: Is there a way may be just to set the path

Comment: You can not modify the JAVA_HOME variable. You can SSH in to the Micro Cloud VM though: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/using-mcf.html#logging-in-to-micro-cloud-foundry

However, you do not get SSH access to hosted Cloud Foundry services like AppFog or CloudFoundry.com.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SSHing (for microcloud) you can use (in vmware player/workstation/fusion) alt+f2 and login. Then use whatever you want. Though VMWare discouraged this, because of updates.